# uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code which is in lib folder. This code works outside of rails, but when it's called from the rails controller I get the uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Base error

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws/s3'

module S3Util

  def self.upload_file(local_file)
    mime_type = "application/octet-stream"
    bucket = "test"

    AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
      :access_key_id     => '*****',
      :secret_access_key => '****'
    )

    base_name = File.basename(local_file)

    puts "**** Uploading #{local_file} as '#{base_name}' to '#{bucket}'"

    AWS::S3::S3Object.store(
      base_name,
      File.open(local_file),
      bucket,
      :content_type => mime_type
    )

    puts "***** Uploaded!"

  end
end
```

Comment: does ::AWS::S3::Base help at all?

Comment: Did you added the Gem to your Gemfile? Please post the line in Gemfile

Comment: gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'

Comment: Any particular reason you are using aws-s3 and aws-sdk?  Don't they provide the same functionality?  Also why is the 3rd require empty?

Comment: How do you call it in the controller?

Comment: third require was a typo. It's not there. I call it as S3Util.upload_file(file_path) from my controller.

Comment: try to require 'aws/s3' inside your S3Util module. There are always such namespacing problems with this aws-s3 gem. And also call it like @menacingly proposed  ::AWS::S3::Base

Comment: Sidenote: Isn't the aws-s3 gem kind of deprecated and now replaced by the `fog` gem?

Answer (score 1):

just do in your controller

```
require 'aws/s3'
```

and its work for me

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't "know" that the module is available to the application; you have to add it to the paths it looks in. You can do that in a couple of ways, but most people do the following.

Add this line to your config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

You may, at some point, want to be more specific about which directories are searched, but this should get you going.

Comment: I did the same what you asked to do but facing same error
**uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Base**